# JLabel and JButton Center in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, centering, boxlayout

I'm newbie in Java programming and can't deal with my Swing problem. I can't get JButtons and JLabels Centred in JPanels(BoxLayout).

Here are some photos :

[image: Here Labels ar Centred, and buttons don't]
[image: Here nothing is centred]

Code:

```
        PlayerLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        PlayerLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        PlayerLabel.setText("Player Level: " + CarMain.main[5]);

    AccessoriesLVL1Label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    AccessoriesLVL1Label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    AccessoriesLVL1Label.setText("<html>Accessories LVL 1<br>" + "Count: " + Part.parts[1]);

JButton jbtnSellAccessoriesLv1 = new JButton("Sell");
jbtnSellAccessoriesLv1.addActionListener(this);
```

And this is where i make Jlabel :

//Upgrades Panel

```
GridLayout UpgradesLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);
        JPanel UpgradesPanel = new JPanel();
        UpgradesPanel.setLayout(UpgradesLayout);

        JPanel UpgradesPanelSub = new JPanel();
        UpgradesPanelSub.setLayout(new BoxLayout(UpgradesPanelSub, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        UpgradesPanelSub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel));

        JPanel UpgradesPanelSub2 = new JPanel();
        UpgradesPanelSub2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(UpgradesPanelSub2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        UpgradesPanelSub2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel));

        JPanel UpgradesPanelSub3 = new JPanel();
        UpgradesPanelSub3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(UpgradesPanelSub3, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        UpgradesPanelSub3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel));

        UpgradesPanelSub.add(Labels.PlayerLabel);
        UpgradesPanelSub.add(jbtnUpgradeLevel);
        UpgradesPanelSub2.add(Labels.GarageLabel);
        UpgradesPanelSub2.add(jbtnUpgradeGarageLevel);
        UpgradesPanelSub3.add(Labels.BoxesLVLLabel);
        UpgradesPanelSub3.add(jbtnUpgradeBoxesLevel);

        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        UpgradesPanel.add(UpgradesPanelSub);
        UpgradesPanel.add(UpgradesPanelSub2);
        UpgradesPanel.add(UpgradesPanelSub3);
        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        UpgradesPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
```

Comment: To reduce confusion I'd suggest you have a look at the Java coding conventions, especially the part where it suggests variable and field names should start with a lower case character (e.g. `upgradesPanel`).

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, sorry for that.. I have readed it, but in this moment, I don't want to rewrite all ~10'000 lines, and check out, where small letter, where big, i will do it later. But thanks for suggestion .

Comment: @Thomas, thanks i found it. Make answer, and i will check it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the layout problem: there's a tutorial on how to use box layout (look for the components' alignment to center them): docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html.

Alternatively you could use one of the external layout managers like MigLayout which are easier to use IMO.